# Failed to deploy react app on github pages, netlify and heroku

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my react app but its not deploying anywhere, I have tried on Github pages, Heroku and Netlify. This is the repo link please someone help.
LINK:- https://github.com/harsh021102/hackat1

Comment: Please give a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Heroku works. https://murmuring-anchorage-77354.herokuapp.com/

1- remove "homepage" from your package.json
2- npm run build
3- copy example project https://github.com/aydink88/heroku-express-spa
4- replace the example project build folder with your build folder
5- push only the express project repo to heroku (netlify and github doesn't work this way)

Comment: I have tried all of three already. If you have time please clone my project and try to host it yourself. I think its not hosting due to CLI errors. Please do check if any one have time it will help me alot.

Comment: @HarshPratapSingh I explained the main steps. Edited above.

Comment: Thank You so much! it worked. Can you provide any insta handle, linkedin or any other way to connect with you.